# How to use Eclipse UML Generators plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, uml

I have installed `Eclipse UML Generators` in eclipse Luna using it's update site. The installation was successful, but there is no documentation in how to use the plugin.

My objective is to generate class diagrams from java code. Can I achieve it from the above plugin?

Comment: I have the same problem, I'm trying to generate a class diagram from my java code, but it's nearly imposible with Eclipse (and supereasy in jdeveloper).. did you find out how to use this plugin?

Comment: Any progress? It is still pretty undocumented.

Answer (score 5):

This question is old, but the answer could help other people :

In the package explorer, right click on the package containing classes about which you want to draw a diagram, select "UML Generators"->Reverse java code

Answer (score 4):

You can use [objectaid](http://www.objectaid.com/class-diagram) plugin to generate digrams in eclipse.well documented.

Comment: i think its an alternate solution but does not answers OP's question

Answer (score 4):

this is the closest i could find to some documentation

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_UML_Generators/New_and_Noteworthy/0.9.0